# Mysql my.cnf empty and mysqltuner

Tags: mysql, performance, my.cnf, mysqltuner

I'm trying to solve a performance issue I have on a Mysql database and to do that I'm using mysqltuner.
What I don't understand is why in phpmyadmin and mysqltuner I have several variable mentioned, whereas when I open the my.cnf file is almost empty. There is the maxconnections parameter only.
Where are stored the other variables ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what mysqltuner comes from

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

`my.cnf` is merely the overrides to the default static `VARIABLES` built into the server.  `STATUS` are counters, etc that change over time.

Note the word `GLOBAL`.  Those are the defaults for the corresponding `SESSION` values that belong to your connection.  The `VARIABLES` you change in phpmyadmin, will not be permanent.  You have to edit `my.cnf` and restart mysqld to get permanent changes.

Usually you *cannot* tune your way out of a performance problem.  Once you have the main cache size set (which engine are you using?  how much ram do you have?), not much other tuning is worth doing.

The main performance gains are from improving the queries and/or the schema, such as adding composite indexes.  Let's see a slow query, and we can discuss this further.

Answer (score 1):

Other variables  are defaults.
My.cnf only override defaults.
You can look for defaults here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: Hi Melanie, sorry but why when I change some variables in phpmyadmin also mysqltuner changes his suggestions and at the same time my.cnf is empty? Where mysqltuner is reading that values ?

Answer (score 0):

MysqlTuner is reading variables and status at the runtime.